# Reading large XML file

Tags: c#, xml, file, parsing, nodes

I have many xml files with the following structure

```
<main.....>
 <raw...>
  <A>field 1</A>
  <B>field 2</B>
  ....
  <interval>
   <type>data</type>
   <type>data</type>
  </interval>
  <interval>
   <type>data</type>
   <type>data</type>
  </interval>
  <interval2>
   <acel>data i need</acel>
   <decel>data i need</decel>
   <left>data i need</left>
   <right>data i need</right>
   <range>tsw</range>
  </interval2>
  <interval2>
   <acel>data i need</acel>
   <decel>data i need</decel>
   <left>data i need</left>
   <right>data i need</right>
   <range>xyz</range>
  </interval2>
 </raw>
 ...
 </raw>
 <raw>
 ...
 </raw>
</main>
```

**I need data from A, and interval2 children acel,decel,lef,right for every raw node in main, I dont know  much about XML. I've gotten to where i get A for every raw, but no further.**

Comment: How large is large?  100MB?  1GB?  1TB?  Can you read the entire file into memory, do you not have enough memory to read in the whole file?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in C# - if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher - is to use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var query = doc.Descendants("raw")
               .Select(raw => new {
                           A = (string) raw.Element("A"),
                           Interval2 = raw.Element("interval2")
                                          .Elements("type2")
                                          .Select(type2 => (string) type2)
                                          .ToList()
                       });

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A: {0}", item.A);
    Console.WriteLine("Interval2 values:");
    foreach (var x in item.Interval2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", x);
    }
}
```

Of course that's just one way of querying it - it's hard to give a more concrete answer without more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have noted LINQ to XML can be extremely slow to parse very large XML files (say 200 KB or more). But it is simple!

Comment: @KevinR: 200K is *not* very large - and I've definitely not seen that behaviour. Any references?

Comment: Whoops! Try 16 MB (half a million lines). Looked at wrong file. I created an XML store for daily air pollution data that takes a good number of seconds to parse, which I felt was slow. Lots of `TryParse` stuff for enums and nullables.

Comment: If the file really is big this may not be the right approach, since it will potentially involve reading quite a lot into memory.  (Which is why I asked the OP about how large he considers "large".)  If the file is excessively large a more stream-based approach may be required.

Comment: actaully in interval2 i have different types, the code gives me: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Servy: It depends on the situation, certainly. It may well be significantly cheaper to buy more memory for the machine that this will run on than to handle code in a streaming way, for example :) But yes, it depends on the size of the file.

Comment: @dean: It's not clear what you mean - but that code should be fine *for the data you've given us*. We can't be expected to anticipate what you haven't told us...

Comment: sorry for being unclear, in inerval2 i have children that have different names, ex. type2, type3 etc

Comment: @dean: Okay, so what have you tried? We can't really help you much unless you're clearer. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet i updated the question, maybe its more clear now. thank you!

Comment: @dean: Well it's not clear why you've got a `NullReferenceException`, as you haven't shown us the code you're using...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use XmlDocument.  However, this reads the entire file into memory so would not be appropriate for immensely large files.